# How to convert Rows to Columns in postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have a simple query output of two rows and single column

```
Virginia
Texas
```

I want the output as

```
Virginia   |  Texas
```

I just tried it as two subqueries in column list.

```
select 
(select state from table where code='VA') as state1
(select state from table where code='TX') as state2
from tablename
```

Is there better way to get the result

Comment: That's not a bad solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for string aggregation?

```
select string_agg(state, ' | ' order by code desc)
from table
where code in ('VA', 'TX')
```

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(state) filter (where code = 'VA'),
       max(state) filter (where code = 'TX')       
from t
where code in ('VA', 'TX')
```

Comment: Hi, I'm actually looking for two columns as output. column1 should have VA and column2 should have TX